# Flutter logi-in as admin using e-mail and password firebase authentication in android app

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have been trying to make a log-in screen that; if an user sign-in with its e-mail and password, they will go to the user screens; however, if an admin sign-in with its admin e-mail and password, the app send admin to the admin page. I have created a method that if an user doesn't have any collection on firestore, the app will give a form to write their informations; if they have a collection on firestore, they go to the user screen.
The code as follows:

An object for authentication

'final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;'

Sign-in with e-mail and password

```
      //sign-in with e-mail and password
  Future signInEmail (String email, String password) async{
    try{
      AuthResult result = await _auth
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Log-in with e-mail and password in entry page

```
//... log-in page UI and form for taking e-mail and password from users
//... 

//log-in via e-mail
  void signIn() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

      dynamic result = await _auth.signInEmail(email, password);

      if (result == null) { // if email is false
        setState(() {
          loading = false;
          error = "Wrong email";
        });
      } else if(firebaseUser.uid == "aMDsuSJ9h6eIJuWX0SvwmXJTvTJ3"){ // tried to find admin with its uid
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AdminHome()));
      } else { // sends to account page
          var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
          final snapShot = await Firestore.instance.collection("membership")
              .document(firebaseUser.uid)
              .get();

          if(snapShot.exists){ // if user has a collection, go to user screens
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AccountHome()));
          } else{ // if user doesn't have any collection, pop-up a dialog
            userInfoDialog(context);
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: how can I make it go to the admin page when an admin log-in? The admin uses same log-in UI with other users. Other users must not go to admin page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the `firebaseUser` reference before the `await _auth.signInEmail`. I would expect `firebaseUser` to be `null`, actually. Are you sure you are not receiving an exception at `firebaseUser.uid`?

You should replace those two lines, as in:

```
      dynamic result = await _auth.signInEmail(email, password);

      var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
```

See if that works.